# how to mobilize an already existing website?

Tags: html, mobile

I'm trying to create a mobile version of my school website is there a simple way to do this? I'd rather not pay money to get some website to do it for me. can I load an external html template instead of just an external css file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find many free and paid tools that help you create mobile sites. Have a look at this [list](http://mashable.com/2010/12/16/create-mobile-site-tools/). I am sure there are many more. If you don't want to pay a penny and you are planning to get some programming experience, you will need some knowledge on HTML5 and CSS.

If you plan for some big and fancy ideas, have a look at [jQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/) or [Sencha Touch](http://sencha.com)

Comment: thanks, the list is very helpful. can I do this with normal css and html or do I have to use CSS3 and HTML5

Comment: you can do it with normal css and html.. html5 and Css3 just add in features and will help you make you site better.

Comment: do you recommend doing it yourself or using something like mobify?

Comment: I am not sure if I can answer that.. it depends on your requirements.. services like this will help you get started quick.. if you don't have time and not planning to program.. then you may go the online services way. Also, @furtive said, you could use wordpress or other CMS.

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can. However, this is no task that can be done automatically. You need to sit down and maybe create a new `HTML` and/or new `CSS`. But you can also just leave it as is, because you can view them on the most smartphones without any problems.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a Content Management System (CMS) such as Wordpress Joomla, or Drupal?  If so, look for a responsive template created in the last year. Another option with some CMSs is a plugin/addon that renders a different template when detecting a mobile device.

If you aren't using a CMS it'll take more work, there are lots of responsive frameworks out there, the two big ones are [Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) and [Zurb Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com).